# C++ adding hex address to address of DLL

Tags: c++, memory

I basically need to get the hex address for a dll of a process and add an offset to that address.
For instance the address I will be adding to the dll is `0x00047420` and I need to add that to the dll from a process. This is going in a trainer for a game and cheat engine gave me this as the base address: `"SDL.dll"+00047420`.

I've tried to just write to `0x00047420` + my pointer offsets when attached to that process but that didn't work.

Comment: Presumably this is Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetModuleHandle("SDL.dll") + 0x00047420